# Use of Konjunktiv II: Why "Ich wünschte", not "ich wünsche"? Compare "I wish" in English!

Tags: grammar, phrase, subjunctive

Man verwendet oft die Wendung "Ich wünschte, …" und meint eigentlich "Ich wünsche [mir], …". Warum kommt hier der Konjunktiv II zum Einsatz? (Oder ist das gar ein Präteritum?) – **Weswegen steht im Englischen dafür nur "I wish" und nicht "I wished"?**

Eine mögliche Erklärung findet sich [hier](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article2038591.html). Behauptet wird, dass "wünschen" hier als "freien Wunsch einlösen" verwendet wird. Stimmt das?

Im Folgenden ein paar Beispiele im Vergleich zu ihren englischen Entsprechungen. Ich hoffe, die Übersetzungen stimmen:

- "Ich wünschte, ich wäre alleine." vs. "I wish I was alone.",
- "Ich wünschte, ihr ließet mich zufrieden." vs. "I wish you'd leave me alone." and
- "Ich wünschte, ich hätte mehr Geld." vs. "I wish I had more money."

Es scheint mir gar nicht so, als wären diese Wünsche unrealistisch – oder ist damit nur gemeint, dass diese Wünsche *momentan unerfüllbar* sind, was dem Sprecher auch bewusst ist, wie man am Konjunktiv im Objektsatz merkt?

Comment: Bzgl. English. Auch wenn es deine Frage nicht zu 100% beantwortet, lies dich hier mal durch: [Can the verb “wish + that clause” express open possibility?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/76384/16833)

Comment: @Em1 Ja, viel Neues steht darin nicht. Mich interessiert derzeit vor allem ein Grund, weswegen es im Englischen anders verwendet wird als im Deutschen, insbesondere weil ich mir davon erhoffe, dass dieser mehr Licht auf die bisherige Erklärung, die ich unbefriedigend finde, werfen wird. (Ich denke auch, man brauchte (oder "bräuchte?) ein viel allgemeineres Sprachwissenschafts-Board, etwa "Indogermanische Sprachen", unter welchem auch die anderen Boards für moderne Sprachen wie dieses subsumiert würden, so dass mehr Austausch herrscht.)

Comment: Interessant finde ich zum Beispiel, dass [hier](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39630/16833) der OP fragt was "I wished I had a nickel" bedeutet und die Antwort sich auf "I wish I had a nickel" bezieht. Das Verhältnis zw. I wished und I wish laut COCA und BNC ist ~9:1, wobei COCA etwa 6x mehr Einträge listet als BNC. Wie auch immer, wie das Ganze im Englischen wirklich gehandhabt wird, keine Ahnung.

Comment: Es ist übrigens imho "man brauche" oder "man brauchte", auch wenn ich tatsächlich "man bräuchte" sagen würde. Interessant aber, dass du hier auch Konjunktiv II verwendest ;) - Wenn du dir jetzt überlegst, warum du nicht Konjunktiv I verwendet hast, kannst du mit ein wenig Überlegung deine Frage teils selbst beantworten :D

Comment: Im Gegensatz zu "Ich wünsche allein zu sein", dem ein Apellcharakter innewohnt hat ein "Ich wünschte, ich wäre alleine." etwas resignatives.

Comment: @userunknown: Genau. In dieselbe Kerbe geht "Was versprichst du dir vom neuen Job?" - "Ich wünsche mir mehr verfügbares Einkommen". Aber am Schufenster des Ferrarihändlers: "Ich wünscshte, ich hätte mehr Geld".

Answer (score 13):

If I'm not mistaken, the use of Konjunktiv II here implies that the speaker knows that his wish is unreal (will not be or can not be fulfilled).

Compare, e.g,.

> "Ich wünsche mir ein rosa Einhorn"

which expresses the actual wish for a pink unicorn, (e.g., a plush toy as a present for Christmas), while

> "Ich wünschte mir ein rosa Einhorn"

means "I would wish for a pink unicorn [, if only it existed]".

Comment: What about "Ich wünschte, ich wäre zuhause". How would you explain that? "I would wish to be at home [if that was possible]"? And how about "Ich wünschte, ihr würdet mich in Ruhne lassen!". These wishes don't seem unreal to me.

Comment: @K.Stm. Wenn dir jmd auf die Nerven geht oder auf die Fresse haut, sagst du dann "Ich wünschte, ihr würdet mich in Ruhe lassen."? - Und das "at home"-Beispiel. Hey klar, wenn ich im Stau stehe, dann könnte ich genau das sagen. Passt doch.

Answer (score 5):

Mein Empfinden ist, dass der Konjunktiv generell ein sehr komplizierter Bestandteil der Grammatik ist – sowohl im Deutschen als auch im Englischen. Eine Antwort aus grammatischer Sicht überlasse ich den Grammatikexperten.

Was ich aber sicherlich anmerken kann, ist, dass der Konjunktiv es schwer hat, wie auch dieser [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-der-traurige-konjunktiv-a-329309.html) feststellt. In der Umgangssprache verwenden wir oft den Indikativ, wo eigentlich Konjunktiv I hingehört, und die *würde*-Variante im Konjunktiv II. Die folgenden Beispiele entnehme ich der [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Umgangssprache):

Konjunktiv I

> Er hat gesagt, dass er ins Theater geht.
>
> Er sagte, dass er ins Theater gehe.

Konjunktiv II

> Er hat gesagt, dass er ins Theater gehen würde.
>
> Er sagte, dass er ins Theater ginge.

Wir machen das, weil wir unsere Schwierigkeiten mit dem Konjunktiv haben. Oft weiß man gar nicht, wie der richtig gebildet wird, wie du in deinem Kommentar eindrucksvoll mit dem Konjunktiv von *brauchen* gezeigt hast (aber ich bilde ihn auch immer falsch).

Ganz kurz möchte ich auf das Englische eingehen. In Coca findet man folgende Treffer:

> I wish I was dead. - 10 hits
>
> I wished I was dead. - 3 hits
>
> I wish I were dead. - 17 hits
>
> I wished I were dead. - 1 hits

Ich habe mir die Beispiele etwas näher angeschaut und versucht Unterschiede auszumachen, ob der Anwender bewusst zu der einen oder anderen Variante gegriffen hat. Tatsächlich ist das der Fall, wie diese Beispiele zeigen:

> By 1991, my lungs were actually burning. I wished I were dead.
>
> Today I am in Yellowstone Park and I wish I were dead.

Hier wird eindeutig zwischen present und past unterschieden, was im Deutschen übrigens nicht mehr gemacht wird. *I wish* drückt eindeutig einen Wunsch aus, den ich jetzt habe, und mit *I wished* wird ein Wunsch eindeutig als vergangen markiert. Das mag aber ein Experte der englischen Sprache weiter ausführen oder widerlegen.

Zurück zum eigentlichen Problem. Der Konjunktiv bereitet dem Deutschen seine Schwierigkeiten. Er wird oft falsch angewendet (bzw. die falsche Konjunktivform verwendet) und im alltäglichen Gerede gilt es dafür, diesen wenn möglich zu vermeiden und durch die beiden oben genannten Varianten zu ersetzen. Hier ein anderes Beispiel:

> Wenn ich du wäre, würde ich jetzt laufen.
>
> Wenn ich du wäre, ??? ich jetzt.

Tja, was ist der Konjunktiv von *laufen*. Konjunktiv I ist *ich laufe*, Konjunktiv 2 ist *ich liefe*. Aber wer weiß das schon. Man sagt es einfach zu selten. Ausnahme sind einige wenige feststehende Phrasen oder Wörter, die man häufiger verwendet. Den Konjunktiv von *sein* kann wirklich jeder bilden:

> Sie sagte, ich sei schön.
>
> Sie sagte, ich wäre schön.

Oh, neue verwandte Frage, was ist richtig? *sei* oder *wäre?* Der durchschnittliche Muttersprachler wählt hier instinktiv *sei,* wenn er der Aussage zustimmt, und *wäre,* wenn er es nicht so sieht. Die oben bereits verlinkte [Wikipedia-Seite](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Konjunktiv_II_in_der_indirekten_Rede) unterstützt meine These.
Dieser instinktive Gebrauch ist durchaus richtig. Bei der indirekten Rede wird in der Regel (fast ausschließlich) der Konjunktiv 1 verwendet. Im Deutschen ist dabei auch egal, ob der Hauptsatz *Er sagt* oder *Er sagte* ist (kein Konjunktiv Present oder Konjunktiv Past). Jedoch ist es so, dass der Konjunktiv 2 tatsächlich für eine indirekte Rede verwendet werden kann, sogar muss, wenn die Unwahrheit einer Aussage ausgedrückt werden soll oder im Kontext eine Aussage als falsch definiert wurde. Auch hierzu ein Beispiel:

> Aufgrund seiner Fahne stellte ich ihn zur Rede, doch er behauptete, er hätte kein Bier getrunken.

Schon wieder vom Thema abgekommen. Ist es nun *Ich wünsche* oder *Ich wünschte*. Auch hier denke ich, ist ein Schema zu erkennen, beobachtet man die Umgangssprache (habe aber keine Quelle gefunden, die das bestätigt oder habe es leider überlesen):

Christoph Wintersteiger bringt es in [seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5289/1224) eigentlich schon auf den Punkt und ich mag es hier kurz wiederholen:

> Ich wünsche mir einen Fußball zu Weihnachten.

Der Wunsch ist realistisch, er muss aber nicht zwingend eintreten. Aber in dem Moment, wo ich es ausspreche, sehe ich gute Chancen, dass der Wunsch erfüllt wird. Wohlbemerkt ist dieser Satz kein Konjunktiv, weder 1 noch 2.

> Ich wünschte, das ganze Chaos würde sich in Luft auflösen.

Der Wunsch hat auch hier durchaus auch Realismus. Auch wenn ich gerade in einer scheinbar aussichtslosen Situation bin, die mich verzweifeln lässt, wird mit Sicherheit der Punkt eintreten, wo sich dieser Wunsch erfüllt. Entscheidend ist, dass ich ausdrücken möchte, dass der Wunsch sich **sofort** erfüllt. Ich will nicht warten, weil es mir auf den Zeiger geht. Es soll jetzt passieren. Basta.

Wie auch immer, Konjunktiv 2 wird immer dann verwendet, wenn es sich um [Irrealis](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis) handelt, sprich, dass der Sprecher nicht an eine Erfüllung glaubt.

Deine Beispiele wird man meistens mit Konjunktiv 2, also *wünschte*, bilden, und zwar dann, wenn du nicht an ihre Erfüllung glaubst. Die ersten beiden kann man aber durchaus auch mit *wünsche* bilden, und zwar dann, wenn du ganz konkret einen Wunsch äußerst, um dessen Erfüllung du quasi bittest.
Das heißt, bist du in einer Diskussion mit jemandem, kannst du ihnen klar machen, dich alleine zu lassen. Du hast gute Chancen, dass sie es tuen. Zugegeben, man formuliert es wohl kaum so, sondern eher mit harschen Worten.
Bist du aber auf einer Party, werden nicht plötzlich alle den Raum verlassen, somit Irrealis. Nur du kannst dir den Wunsch nur selber erfüllen, indem du gehst. Aber dann musst du es dir gar nicht mehr wünschen, wenn du es in der Hand hast, oder?

Letztlich, den spontanen Geldsegen halte ich hingegen für sehr unrealistisch, daher immer Konjunktiv 2: *wünschte*.

Comment: Mir kommt es falsch vor, die ersten beiden Beispiele mit "wünschen" zu bilden. Dass "wünschen" hier im Konjunktiv II steht, scheint mir, ohne auf die unterschiedlichen semantischen Nuancen des Verbs einzugehen, ebensoschwer beantwortbar zu sein, wie ohne einen Vergleich des Konjunktivs mit dem Englischen anzustellen. Bei einer anderen Frage ist zur Verwendung des Konjunktivs außerdem [hierauf](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/optativ-potentialis-konjunktiv.php) verwiesen worden. Ich verwende übrigens oft den korrekten Konjunktiv II wie etwa "liefe", vor allem bei so stark gebeugten Verben.

Comment: @K.Stm. Der von dir verlinkte Artikel ist interessant; allgemein sind alle Artikel auf der Seite sehr aufschlussreich. Ich gehe nicht soweit und vergleiche diese mit dem Amen in der Kirche, aber die Basis auf denen diese Artikel geschrieben wurden, ist ausgesprochen fundiert. - Bzgl. deiner drei Beispiele. Mir kommen die *wünsche*-Form nicht falsch vor - sondern ungewohnt. Man formuliert sowas nicht in der Art, wie ich es angedeutet habe, sondern verwendet eher den Imparativ. Das war auch meine Intention im Kommentar zu der anderen Antwort.

Answer (score 3):

'Ich wünschte, …' (K II) drückt einen Wunschzustand aus, von dessen Nicht-Eintreffen (jetzt oder überhaupt) der Sprecher von vornherein ausgeht, sei es tatsächlich oder bloß rhetorisch (z.B. als indirekter Appell).

> • Ich wünschte, die Woche wäre schon zu Ende.
>   • Ich wünschte, ich hätte den Döner nicht gegessen.
>   • Ich wünschte, du würdest öfter duschen.
>   • Ich wünschte, der Weihnachtsmann würde mir eine Million Euro bringen.

'Ich wünsche …' ist dagegen der schlichte, direkte Ausdruck eines Wunsches, unabhängig davon, ob er erfüllbar ist oder auch nicht. In diesem Satz ist dann kein Konjunktiv II.

Ich bin kein Linguist, aber weshalb es im Englischen als korrekter Standard gilt, im ersten Satzteil 'wish' und nicht 'wished' zu benutzen, lässt sich wahrscheinlich nur sprachhistorisch erklären. Interessanterweise machen aber manche Englisch-Muttersprachler, offenbar besonders Nordamerikaner, den "Fehler", statt 'I wish' 'I wished' zu sagen. Ob das wohl reiner Zufall ist?

Answer (score 1):

I would not say German "Ich wünschte* ich hätte* mehr Zeit" (* Past subjunctive)  is particular as it is an irreal wish.
I would say English "I wish I had* more time" is particular as it uses "wish"
(Present indicative) although the wish can't be fulfilled. So Germans have to learn this special sentence type where Present indicative is used as a form of irrealis and it is a special point in grammars of English.

Sorry, I got confused and wrote in English.