# Ist "ich wünschte" ein Anglizismus?

Tags: word-usage, anglicism, pseudo-anglicism

Die Redewendung "ich wünschte" war schon Gegenstand mehrerer Fragen, z.B. [dieser](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5288/34192). Hier ist die Verwendung in Sätzen der Form

> Ich wünschte, es wäre schon Wochenende.

> Ich wünschte, Du wärest bei mir.

gemeint. Ich habe den Eindruck, dass das durch Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen (vgl. "wish you were here" von Pink Floyd) ins Deutsche vorgedrungen ist, aber mittlerweile sehr häufig verwendet wird. Was führt mich zu dieser Ansicht?

- Im Deutschen würde man m.E. eher "Ich wünschte [oder wünsche] **mir**, es wäre schon Wochenende" sagen. D.h. im Sinne von "sich etwas wünschen" - transitiv mit Dativ. Eine Alternative ist auch "Wäre es doch schon Wochenende!"
- "Frühe" Belege konnte ich nur wenige finden. Hier ein [Beispiel](https://www.fischerverlage.de/buch/stefan-zweig-ich-wuenschte-dass-ich-ihnen-ein-wenig-fehlte-9783596950041) aus einem Brief von Stefan Zweig:

> Ich wünschte, dass ich Ihnen ein wenig fehlte.

Stefan Zweigs Brief entstand im Zeitraum 1934 - 1940 während der Zeit seines Exils in London, eine Beeinflussung durch die englische Sprache ist daher denkbar.

- Der Wellington zugeschriebene Ausspruch bei der Schlacht bei Waterloo "Ich wollte, es wäre Nacht oder die Preußen kämen" deutet darauf hin, dass früher eher "ich wollte" statt "ich wünschte" gesagt wurde wurde. Auch das hat sich teilweise schon dem Zeitgeschmack angepasst, vgl [hier](https://www.welt.de/kultur/article8072805/Die-Schlacht-von-Waterloo-bleibt-immer-aktuell.html):

> In dieser Situation soll Wellington den berühmten Satz „I want night or Blucher!“ gesagt haben, der in der Regel mit „Ich wünschte es wäre Nacht, oder die Preußen kämen“ übersetzt wird.

Comment: Ist "wünschte mir" nicht ein Wunsch an sich selbst, aber "wünschte" (ohne "mir") nicht ein Wunsch generell ("an alle" einschließlich "mir")?

Comment: @äüö Im "Wochend-Beispiel" könnte es ggf. so sein, dass sich der Wunsch an alle richtet. Ich habe ein weiteres Beispiel beigefügt.

Comment: Vermischt du in deiner Frage nicht zwei Sachen? 1. "sich wünschen" vs. "wünschen" und 2. "wünschen" vs. "wollen"? Und wie wäre es, zu beiden Fragen mal in deutschen Korpora zu suchen? Hier z. B. wünschen vs. wollen: https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=zeitungen&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=1&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1946%3A2019&q1=wollen&q2=w%C3%BCnschen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wahrscheinlich nicht.

Natürlich ist es immer schwierig zu beweisen, dass etwas nicht so ist, wie behauptet und natürlich kann die Verwendung eines Begriffs sich durch fremden kulturellen Einfluss verstärken oder besonders etablieren.

Aber hier mal ein empirischer Ansatz. Gibt man "ich wünschte dass" vs "ich wünsche mir dass" bei Google Books Ngram Viewer ein [erhält man](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20dass%2Cich%20w%C3%BCnsche%20mir%20dass&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=0)

[image]

bei "ich wünschte dass" vs "ich wünsche mir dass" vs "ich wünsche mir es" vs "ich wünschte es" folgenden [Graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20dass%2Cich%20w%C3%BCnsche%20mir%20dass%2Cich%20w%C3%BCnsche%20mir%20es%2C%20ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=0&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20dass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cich%20w%C3%BCnsche%20mir%20dass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cich%20w%C3%BCnsche%20mir%20es%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Was die nicht-transitive Verwendung über die Zeit als stets dominant erscheinen lässt. Zumindest bis Anfang 2000er.

Natürlich gibt es da auch sehr viel "Beifang", der nicht zu der Frage passt, allerdings lassen sich über die von Google bereitgestellten Links (bei den Graphen) mehr als genug "frühe" Belege finden, was unabhängig davon deine Vermutung schon unwahrscheinlich macht.

> Ich wünschte, es gelange ihr, seine Liebe zu zerstören

"So geht es in der Welt" - [1808](https://books.google.de/books?id=7VxZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA318&dq=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA6ru774zuAhVwwAIHHZMfDi0Q6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es%22&f=false)

> Ich wünschte, es gäb' einmal eine Akademie die Preisfrage auf: was man für Preisfragen aufgeben sollte.

"Zeitung für die elegante Welt Berlin" - [1808](https://books.google.de/books?id=94hEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1801&dq=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA6ru774zuAhVwwAIHHZMfDi0Q6AEwBXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es%22&f=false)

> Ich wünschte, es wäre möglich, diese Geschäfte sicher vorher zu wissen.

"Grundsätze der Erziehung und des Unterrichts" - [1802](https://books.google.de/books?id=njZNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA38&dq=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqrd3Z8YzuAhVS3KQKHancATE4ChDoATABegQIAxAC#v=onepage&q=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20es%22&f=false)

> Ich wünschte, daß es so käme.

"Wörterbuch der deutschen sprache - Band 1" - [1807](https://books.google.de/books?id=5qYxAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA687&dq=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20dass%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPjaWK8ozuAhWI6aQKHS8XDCoQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ich%20w%C3%BCnschte%20dass%22&f=false)

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, die frühen Belege sind überzeugend!